# Databinding error when using different applicationID in flavor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After updating to Android studio 2.0 preview 2 I get following error when compiling against beta flavor which has suffix .beta:

app build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
        beta {
            applicationId 'com.example.app.beta'
        }
        production {
            applicationId 'com.example.app'
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
Error:(38, 44) error: package com.example.app.databinding does not exist
```

When compiling against production flavor, everything is fine. The most puzzling thing is that this error occurs only when running the app (not during gradle sync)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem appeared when I was creating `productFlavors` and also tried to set `sourceSets`.
In the end I found out that the problem was caused by an incorrect path set to the
`res` folder in the `sourceSets` setup.

Changing

```
sourceSets {
    develop {
        res.srcDirs = ['wrong/path/src/develop/res']
    }
```

to

```
sourceSets {
    develop {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/develop/res']
    }
}
```

solved my issue.